# Could not find or load main class hdfs problem

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop3

I am trying to use Apache Rya for some tests (https://rya.apache.org/).

For those who are familiar with Rya and RDF stores, I am trying to do a bulk loading which is explained here: https://github.com/apache/rya/blob/master/extras/rya.manual/src/site/markdown/loaddata.md.

Briefly, I should copy a Jar file 'mapreduce/target/rya.mapreduce--shaded.jar' into an hdfs volume then run the following command:

```
hadoop hdfs://volume/rya.mapreduce-<version>-shaded.jar org.apache.rya.accumulo.mr.tools.RdfFileInputTool -Dac.zk=localhost:2181 -Dac.instance=accumulo -Dac.username=root -Dac.pwd=secret -Drdf.tablePrefix=rya_ -Drdf.format=N-Triples hdfs://volume/dir1,hdfs://volume/dir2,hdfs://volume/file1.nt
```

Well I copied the needed Jar and the input files into hdfs and verified that they are really there using `bin/hadoop fs -put` command. My problem is that when I run the cmd in the official example I get the following lines of error that I could not understand or resolve.

```
/project/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2393: HADOOP_HDFS://LOCALHOST:9000/USER/RYA.MAPREDUCE-4.0.0-INCUBATING-SHADED.JAR_USER: invalid variable name
/project/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2358: HADOOP_HDFS://LOCALHOST:9000/USER/RYA.MAPREDUCE-4.0.0-INCUBATING-SHADED.JAR_USER: invalid variable name
/project/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2453: HADOOP_HDFS://LOCALHOST:9000/USER/RYA.MAPREDUCE-4.0.0-INCUBATING-SHADED.JAR_OPTS: invalid variable name
Error: Could not find or load main class hdfs:..localhost:9000.user.rya.mapreduce-4.0.0-incubating-shaded.jar
```

For information; all env variables are properly set, HADOOP_HOME and HADOOP_PREFIX

Comment: I'd try running the jar from a local path, not HDFS.

Comment: Okey, I have tries running this cmd: ` bin/hadoop jar /project/rya/mapreduce/target/rya.mapreduce-4.0.0-incubating-shaded.jar org.apache.rya.accumulo.mr.tools.RdfFileInputTool -Dac.zk=localhost:2181 -Dac.instance=accumulo -Dac.username=root -Dac.pwd=secret -Drdf.tablePrefix=rya_ -Drdf.format=N-Triples /user/root/file.nt`, but I got another problem: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem cannot access its superinterface org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.TokenAspect$TokenManagementDelegator`